# How to stop tmux capturing key sequences?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, tmux

My `xterm` is configured to produce this sequence:

```
Ctrl ~Shift <Key>Tab: string(0x1b) string("[27;5;9~") \n\
```

Under `tmux` it almost always does not work (sometimes it passes through). What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

`tmux` has a table of escape-sequence patterns in the `xterm-keys.c` file so that it can support xterm-style modified special keys.  It matches this pattern:

```
        { '\t',         "\033[27;_;9~" },
```

to your string `\033[27;5;9~` using the underscore character as a wildcard.  The table maps escape sequences into things that `tmux` knows about:

- special keys, with <kbd>control</kbd> and <kbd>shift</kbd> modifiers
- *other* keys where `tmux` ignores those modifiers

Normally it translates your escape sequence into a <kbd>tab</kbd> character, which you might not notice (aside from perhaps triggering name-completion).  If you hold the key down, you'll get the keyboard to repeat rapidly enough that `tmux` will lose track of the timing, and allow the individual bytes to pass through (a limitation of function-key recognition).

If an incoming escape sequence does not match one of those patterns, and is not found in the list of special keys from the terminal description, `tmux` is likely to discard the input altogether (subject to misinterpretation due to key-repeat, etc).